# Howto increase width of Address toolbar history dropdown?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, autohotkey

I found "Address" toolbar of the Win7 taskbar useful to choose any address from history dropdown, e.g. folder that you wish to open. So in 2 clicks you open any frequently used folder, without the need in many shortcuts, bookmarks, or entering "Start" menus, typing, searching etc. or starting file explorer or some additional tool...

The problem is that the width of the drop-down list is small, you don't see the pull path, that's the pain. Esp. when you use taskbar on the side of the screen.

I found a good tip from Alec Soroudi to use Autohotkey to modify controls.

[How can I shrink the Address toolbar in the Task Bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/444407/how-can-i-shrink-the-address-toolbar-in-the-task-bar/445385)

SetAddressBarWidth.ahk

Could Alec or someone show how to increase the width of "Address" bar history list?
(I can't comment there as I'm new to the site, don't have rep. Sorry).
Or just tell me the name of that control? The rest is easy.

(I know I can use some "windows-inspecting" software, but it'd be long research for the newbie. Thanks).

PS. If nobody will care to answer, then I'll search for myself, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as big as you like (to the limits of the available size on your taskbar) without any custom modifications.  Just make sure the option to `Lock your taskbar` is not checked when you right-click elsewhere on the taskbar.  When it's not locked you can just drag it to be wider.

The AutoHotkey script you link to is only useful if you want to make the bar smaller than the default minimum limit is.  You can change the value listed for min (i.e., `min:=200` instead of `min:=0`) if you want to set the bar to a certain size without the refresh icon, but after doing that, if you resize it by dragging on the taskbar it will reset any custom modifications.